# Python Mock a function imported into a Function

Tags: python

I have looked at several of the other answers but they didn't solve my issue. I am trying to mock a method imported in another module.
Here is my layout:
**app/db/some_data.py**

```
def method_to_get_data():
    query_logic...
```

***app/query/some_querys.py**

```
from some_data import method_to_get_data
DATA = method_to_get_data()
```

**app/app.py**

```
import some_querys as query
logic....
```

**app/test/test_app.py**

```
@patch("app.query.method_to_get_data", side_effect=useful_mock()
def test_method(self, mock_useful): ...
```

I have tried a few permutations but have not had much success. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does your `patch` do? What have you *actually* tried, show us some code? And what do you mean other answers didn't solve your issue? What is the error(s) you are getting (if any)? Why do you even try to mock the function?

Comment: It complains that there is not a path to the DB (which is correct since I dont want it to connect to the DB) and then dies. The reason it does this is because my patch (which just returns back 1 is not being called. I have search on SO but everyone seems to only go 1 level of mocking down and I need to go 2 levels. an import and a from not just on or the other.